# Diameter of $\epsilon$-neigbourhood of a set

Tags: calculus, analysis, metric-spaces

In $\mathbb{R}^n$, with usual $l^2$ norm, suppose $E$ is a non-empty subset, we can approximate $E$ by a open set , namely the $\epsilon$-neighbourhood of $E$.
Denote as $E_{\varepsilon}:=\lbrace y:\exists x \in E, d(x,y)<\varepsilon \rbrace$.
My question a how can I prove $diamE_\varepsilon= diamE + 2\varepsilon$?
My attempt is try to prove by showing inequality of both sides. $diamE_\varepsilon \leq diamE + 2\varepsilon$ is clear by taking supremum over E and triangle inequality.
I am stuck at the part of  proving the other direction.
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Let $x,y \in E, x \neq y$ and $0<\delta <\epsilon$. Look at the line joining $x$ and $y$. We can pick points $x',y'$ in this line such that $\|x'-y'\|=\|x-y\|+2\delta$ and $x',y' \in E_{\epsilon}$. Now $\|x-y\|+2\delta=\|x'-y'\| \leq Diam (E_{\epsilon})$. Can you finish?

Explicitly, you can  take $x'=x-\delta \frac {y-x} {\|y-x\|}$ and $y'=x+\delta \frac {y-x} {\|y-x\|}$.